# Utf7Encoding Text truncation

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, utf-7

I was having an issue with the Utf7Encoding class truncating the '+4' sequence.
I would be very interested to know why this was happening. 
I tried Utf8Encoding for getting string from the byte[] array and it seem to work honky dory.
Are there any known issues like that with Utf8? Essentially I use the output produced by this conversion to construct html out of rtf string.

Here is the snippet:

```
    UTF7Encoding utf = new UTF7Encoding(); 
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(); 

    string test = "blah blah 9+4"; 

    char[] chars = test.ToCharArray(); 
    byte[] charBytes = new byte[chars.Length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++) 
    { 

        charBytes[i] = (byte)chars[i]; 

     }


    string resultString = utf8.GetString(charBytes); 
    string resultStringWrong = utf.GetString(charBytes); 

    Console.WriteLine(resultString);  //blah blah 9+4  
    Console.WriteLine(resultStringWrong);  //blah 9
```

Comment: Is this C#? If so you might want to tag it as such.

Comment: Interesting find, definitely not expected behavior.

Comment: Actually, I think you are looking for ASCII encoding, utf-7 I suspect is also encoded like utf-8.

Comment: I am just reluctant to proceed to fixing this with the Utf8Encoding as I am not convinced there would not be other issues. And I can not have any truncation on my data as I deal with medical info...Really want to find out if this is a bug and why this is happening at the deeper level. I have not started reflecting yet but feeling that might be the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to byte array through char array like that does not work.  If you want the strings as charset-specific `byte[]` do this:

```
UTF7Encoding utf = new UTF7Encoding();
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

string test = "blah blah 9+4";

byte[] utfBytes = utf.GetBytes(test);
byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(test);

string utfString = utf.GetString(utfBytes);
string utf8String = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

Console.WriteLine(utfString);  
Console.WriteLine(utf8String);
```

Output:

> blah blah 9+4
>
> blah blah 9+4

Comment: OK, so why the Utf8Encoding treats the wrong constructed byte array in the way I would expect?

Comment: Sheer good luck that the `char` and `byte` representations coincide - in the general case, your `Encoding` class used to map from `string` to `byte[]` could be the one for any multibyte charset.  `string` is always Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Your are not transating the string to utf7 bytes correctly. You should call `utf.GetBytes()` instead of casting the characters to a byte.

I suspect that in utf7 the ascii code corresponding to '+' is actually reserved for encoding international unicode characters.